# VBA code for inserting unique text to each of 12 cells, when cells are blank

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and am severely stuck! I have 12 cells that I need to add specific text to, but only if the cells are blank. I managed to find code for 1 of them which is shown below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$D$3" Then
        If Target.Value = "Insert name of project (if known)" Then
            Target.Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            Target.Value = ""
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If [D3].Value = "" Then
        [D3].Value = "Insert name of project (if known)"
        [D3].Font.ColorIndex = 1
    Else
        [D3].Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End If
End Sub
```

However, seemingly I can only use this once per sheet. I need code that is similar to this that will hopefully do the same job. The remaining 11 cells need to have unique text.

Basically what I am trying to do is prompt the user to insert details in each of these cells and once the cells are filled, the form will be complete.

Any assistance is appreciated.

---

Hi, Apologies for the delay. This is the final edit, which works perfectly. I thought I was going to have an issue with 'undo' (CTRL+Z) but it seems to be fine now. Thanks again.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim clls(1 To 12) As String
    Dim msg(1 To 12) As String
    Dim i As Long, addr As String, c As Range

    clls(1) = "D3": msg(1) = "Insert name of project (if known)"
    clls(2) = "D4": msg(2) = "Insert closest street address"
    clls(3) = "H3": msg(3) = "Insert name of landowner (if applicable)"
    clls(4) = "H4": msg(4) = "Insert name of Developer (if applicable)"
    clls(5) = "H6": msg(5) = "Insert name of PM Co. (if different from above)"
    clls(6) = "H7": msg(6) = "Insert name of Designer (if applicable)"
    clls(7) = "H8": msg(7) = "Insert name of Constructor"
    clls(8) = "L3": msg(8) = "Insert project number (if known)"
    clls(9) = "L6": msg(9) = "Insert name"
    clls(10) = "L7": msg(10) = "Insert submission date"
    clls(11) = "D10": msg(11) = "Brief description of project: Adjustment, deviation, main upsizing, main extension, lead-in, lead-out, etc."
    clls(12) = "D11": msg(12) = "Insert length of asset (number only)"

    Set c = Target.Cells(1)
    addr = c.Address(False, False)

    For i = 1 To UBound(clls)

        If addr = clls(i) Then
            If c.Value = msg(i) Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                c.Value = ""
            End If
        Else
            With Me.Range(clls(i))
                If .Value = "" Then
                    .Value = msg(i)
                    .Font.ColorIndex = 1
                End If
            End With
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What are the cells you need to apply this to?  D3, and?  Is it D3:D14?  Also, when you say "Insert name of project (if known)", is that where you'd want the user's input?  Where are you getting that info from, because the code you have will SET the value, and if it needs to be unique, where is the source?

Comment: Why: 1) do you use SelectionChange event? 2) do you need such as functionality? 3) what you mean by "form will be complete", if you use sheet object? Please, clarify what you need and why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might need a bit of tweaking...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim clls(1 To 5) As String
    Dim msg(1 To 5) As String
    Dim i As Long, addr As String, c As Range

    clls(1) = "D3": msg(1) = "Message 1"
    clls(2) = "D4": msg(2) = "Message 2"
    clls(3) = "D5": msg(3) = "Message 3"
    clls(4) = "D6": msg(4) = "Message 4"
    clls(5) = "D7": msg(5) = "Message 5"

    Set c = Target.cells(1)
    addr = c.Address(False, False)

    For i = 1 To UBound(clls)

        If addr = clls(i) Then
            If c.Value = msg(i) Then
                c.Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                c.Value = ""
            End If
        Else
            With Me.Range(clls(i))
                If .Value = "" Then
                    .Value = msg(i)
                    .Font.ColorIndex = 1
                End If
            End With
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Absolute genious. Thanks a million. I tweaked it a little:

Comment: Typically you can edit your own question to add your final code.